# using Hibernate to loading 20K products, modifying the entity and updating to db

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, data-processing

I am using hibernate to update 20K products in my database.

As of now I am pulling in the 20K products, looping through them and modifying some properties and then updating the database.

so:

```
load products

foreach products
   session begintransaction
   productDao.MakePersistant(p);
   session commit();
```

As of now things are pretty slow compared to your standard jdbc, what can I do to speed things up?

I am sure I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Did you really mean *N*Hibernate (in the title)?

Comment: Not for Java - NHibernate is for .NET.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you meant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The right place to look at in the documentation for this kind of treatment is the whole [Chapter 13. Batch processing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/batch.html).

Here, there are several obvious mistakes in your current approach:

- you should not start/commit the transaction for each update.
- you should enable JDBC batching and set it to a reasonable number (10-50):

  ```
  hibernate.jdbc.batch_size 20
  ```
- you should `flush()` and then `clear()` the session at regular intervals (every n records where n is equal to the `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` parameter) or it will keep growing and may explode (with an `OutOfMemoryException`) at some point.

Below, the example given in the section [13.2. Batch updates](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/batch.html) illustrating this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

ScrollableResults customers = session.getNamedQuery("GetCustomers")
    .setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
    .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
int count=0;
while ( customers.next() ) {
    Customer customer = (Customer) customers.get(0);
    customer.updateStuff(...);
    if ( ++count % 20 == 0 ) {
        //flush a batch of updates and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

You may also consider using the [StatelessSession](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession).

Another option would be to use [DML-style operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct) (in HQL!): `UPDATE FROM? EntityName (WHERE where_conditions)?`. This the HQL UPDATE example:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

String hqlUpdate = "update Customer c set c.name = :newName where c.name = :oldName";
// or String hqlUpdate = "update Customer set name = :newName where name = :oldName";
int updatedEntities = s.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
        .setString( "newName", newName )
        .setString( "oldName", oldName )
        .executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Again, refer to the documentation for the details (especially how to deal with the `version` or `timestamp` property values using the `VERSIONED` keyword).

Answer (score 5):

If this is pseudo-code, I'd recommend moving the transaction outside the loop, or at least have a double loop if having all 20K products in a single transaction is too much:

```
load products
foreach (batch)
{
   try
   {
      session beginTransaction()
      foreach (product in batch)
      {
          product.saveOrUpdate()
      }
      session commit()
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace()
       session.rollback()
   }
}
```

Also, I'd recommend that you batch your UPDATEs instead of sending each one individually to the database.  There's too much network traffic that way.  Bundle each chunk into a single batch and send them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer above about looking at the chapter on batch processing.

I also wanted to add that you should make sure that you only load what is neccessary for the changes that you need to make for the product.

What I mean is, if the product eagerly loads a large number of other objects that are not important for this transaction, you should consider not loading the joined objects - it will speed up the loading of products and depending on their persistance strategy, may also save you time when making the product persistent again.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest possible way to do a batch update would be to convert it to a single SQL statement and execute it as raw sql on the session.  Something like

```
update TABLE set (x=y) where w=z;
```

Failing that you can try to make less transactions and do updates in batches:

```
start session
start transaction

products = session.getNamedQuery("GetProducs")
    .setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
    .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
count=0;
foreach product
    update product
    if ( ++count % 20 == 0 ) {
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

commit transaction
close session
```

For more information look at the [Hibernate Community Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-update)